# Connect external load balancer to the on-premise service fabric cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric, f5

How to connect external load balancer (for example F5) to the Service Fabric on-premise cluster?
It's already done by Azure, since Service Fabric deployed in Azure with Azure LB make round-robin for stateless instances.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you hosting stateless web front-end in Fabric? If so, you can configure this service to be on each node and round-robin your load balancer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598366/can-i-use-load-balancer-for-scaling-azure-service-fabric-apps

Comment: I have 3K requests per second, and cannot rely on the LB in service fabric. And additional logic of LB exists (pool prioritization, custom readiness).

Comment: I mean your external LB.

Comment: Ok. In this case I will loose service discovery (via NamingService), that will be done by F5 (via pool).

Comment: What I have in mind: You have 1 gateway stateless service which is called directly by external LB. This service is very lightweight - its only task is to route the request to the other Service Fabric service with all the benefits of SF internals. Let's see if others can advise anything better though...

Comment: First of all, the Azure LB that you get does not use have any kind of Service Discovery either, it's just round-robin So the options you have is as Mikhail says. I'd go for the gateway service. Host it on every node (or X nodes), round-robin to that one from LB, and then in that one do Service Discovery /Routing based on headers/URI/something else.

Comment: thanks guys for help.

Comment: @acdev have you done anything in that direction? I'm having the same problem and was wandering if you could share your experience and any solutions you came up with?