# Azure service fabric - return result after long time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

I'm using azure service fabric for our new service.

For the client-facing gateway I have a stateless service getting request, the actual work is done using reliable stateless actors.

As suggested by [Sean McKenna - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069069/sean-mckenna-msft) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986584/azure-service-fabric-usage), I put the incoming request in a ReliableQueue and storing the result in a ReliableDictionary.

The actors work time can take up to 10 minutes, So my question is how to push back the results to the client after such a long time?

Client side polling is not possible in our case.

For a start I'll need to support up to 10k request per day, later on it will get higher, much higher.

Comment: Maybe use something like Firebase/SignalR push the results around?

Comment: I though using SignalR, but it seems SignalR is much more for broadcasting to the entire group (like IRC) , not for a single client, I saw some suggestion how to signal a single user, just want to make sure that is the best way. like in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522103/signalr-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-user-using-iuseridprovider-new-2-0

Comment: I'm sure it would be fine, you can choose which user to send your data too. It's normal for a typical chat application to only send to a single user and SignalR is setup for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Fabric doesn't limit you in any way when it comes to something like this - you should try and approach the problem as you would in any other platform.

You can use a pub/sub solution (e.g. Service Bus) or the client could even provide an API that can receive status updates from the actor/service.

Comment: I liked the idea of having the client provide an API for updates. 10x

Comment: Cool - please consider marking the question as answered :)

Comment: of course buddy, let me test several things and see any other alternatives